# Why is my RemoteFunction not firing inside of PlayerAdded event

Tags: lua, roblox

The client sends a message to the server after a class is selected from a UI. The server sets up default DataStore2 values and listens for updates to send info back to client. My idea was to have the RemoteFunctions's server invoke add the class to the datastore and send the class back to the client (for stats gui). The function does not fire inside of PlayerAdded. The function does however fire outside of the event, but the callRemote() function inside of what the Remote executes requires a variable from the event. Suggestions?

```
--server
data.Combine("DATA","gold","sh_coins","class")

spawn(function()
    glbs.Plrs.PlayerAdded:connect(function(Plr)

        local goldstore = data("gold",Plr)
        local shcoinstore = data("sh_coins",Plr)
        local classstore = data("class",Plr)

        function callRemote(remote,value)
            sendDataToClient:InvokeClient(Plr,remote,value)
        end

        callRemote('Gold',goldstore:Get(500))
        callRemote('Stronghold Coins',shcoinstore:Get(0))
        callRemote('Class',classstore:Get('None'))

        goldstore:OnUpdate(callRemote)
        shcoinstore:OnUpdate(callRemote)
        classstore:OnUpdate(callRemote)

        classSelected.OnServerInvoke = function(plr,Class)
            print('class remote called: '..Class)
            callRemote('Class',classstore:Set(Class))
        end

    end)
end)
```

```
--client
local function connectClasses() --to play button
    for _,v in pairs(menuclass:GetChildren()) do
        wait()
        if v:IsA('TextButton') then 
            if v.Name ~= 'Back' then 
                local inf = tinfo(.5,Enum.EasingStyle.Elastic)
                spawn(function()
                    v.Button.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
                        --print('clickitied')
                        spawn(function()
                            ClassSelected:InvokeServer(v.Name)
                        end)
                        local goal = {}
                        goal.Position = menuout
                        local t0 = twn(menuclass,inf,goal)
                        t0.Completed:wait()
                        gbls.Debris:AddItem(startmenu,0)
                        spawned = true
                        main.Enabled = true
                        cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
                    end)
                end)
            end
        end     
    end
end

--update stats on data load (handled by server)
function updateStats(stat,val)
    menuf[stat].Text = stat..': '..val
end
--listen for data load
StatUpdate.OnClientInvoke = updateStats
```

Comment: How is `glbs.Plrs` defined? If you put print statements inside the PlayerAdded connection, do those show up when you would expect them to?

Comment: why can't you just add other variables that you need in callRemote() to its signature, if it works outside of the event handler? Like:  callRemote(plr,remote,value)  - or is there a bigger picture missing here?